# Plug in this flash drive?

Tags: usb-flash-drive

I really don't know how to use it, it looks like an USB but it doesn't fit anywhere. It looks like this:

https://recoverit.wondershare.com/images/article/10/credit-card-flash-drive.jpg

(This is an image I found, mine isn't actually a credit card)

Comment: Surprisingly enough it fits into a USB port. See [How to plug a thin promo USB Drive into a computer? - PromotionalDrives](https://promotionaldrives.com/blog/how-to-plug-a-thin-promo-usb-drive-into-a-computer/)

Answer (score 1):

It is just missing the case, All USBs are basically like that, but normally the USB has a metal shell around it. Just plug it in as if there was a metal case around the USB and your part needs to go where there is an empty space in the PC-USB-Port.